# Personal Names matching in JavaScript

Tags: natural-language, matching, javascript

According to [this](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~Peter.Christen/publications/tr-cs-06-02.pdf) paper: `A Comparison of Personal Name Matching: Techniques and Practical Issues`

several techniques are possibile in personal names matching, that is the matching of names like ‘`Gail Vest` and `Gayle West`, `Robert` and `Bob`, or `Dave Bourget` and `David F. Bourget` etc.

Those techniques will have different results in terms of accuracy and performances.

In Python there are some solutions implemented like [name_tools](https://github.com/openstates/name_tools) and in perl as well like [Names](http://search.cpan.org/~dbourget/Text-Names-0.19/lib/Text/Names.pm) modules.

I'm searching for a similar implementations in Javascript/Node.js

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't find one, it probably doesn't exist. But you can always try translating the Python or Perl one into JavaScript.